# Move automaticaly row selected on JTable and doesn't desappear on view

Tags: jtable, jscrollpane

I have a Jtable in scrollepane with more rows, I'd like that selection move automaticaly on top when scroll-up and on bottum scroll-down, but actually, the selection desppear on view as default when scrolling

I've looked everywhere for solutions but I can't find for them.